# Xamarin iOS trait collection warning error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

In my project, I used the implementation described in this link

https://nshint.github.io/blog/2015/09/23/uitraitcollection-trick

However when building the project, the console is showing a lot of warnings as you can see below

> [Assert] A trait environment returned a trait collection with unspecified values for traits that are not allowed to be unspecified. This is a serious application bug and will cause undefined behavior. This issue may be caused by your class overriding the traitCollection property getter, which is not supported. Make sure to use the appropriate API if you are trying to override traits.

I have looked and tried different implementations, but all of them use storyboards and I don’t use that in my project(I'm using xib only).

Is this something I need to be worried about or this is a good implementation?

```
public abstract partial class BaseControllerView<TPresenter> : UIViewController, IView
    where TPresenter : BasePresenter
{
    public BaseControllerView(string nibName, NSBundle bundle)
        : base(nibName, bundle)
    {
    }


    public override UITraitCollection TraitCollection => GetTraitCollection();

    ....

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
    }

    UITraitCollection GetTraitCollection()
    {
        if (!IsLandscape)
        {
            var traisCollection = new[] { UITraitCollection.FromHorizontalSizeClass(UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.Compact), UITraitCollection.FromVerticalSizeClass(UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.Regular) };
            return UITraitCollection.FromTraitsFromCollections(traisCollection);
        }
        else
        {
            var traisCollection = new[] { UITraitCollection.FromHorizontalSizeClass(UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.Compact), UITraitCollection.FromVerticalSizeClass(UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.Compact) };
            return UITraitCollection.FromTraitsFromCollections(traisCollection);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could post the relevant code about traitCollection , which will be helpful to find out the cause .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I added the problematic code.Thank you

Comment: Check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection?changes=_7&language=objc